# how to add event on subitem on contextmenustrip? C#

Tags: c#, contextmenu

```
for (int i = 0; i < client.Folders.Count; i++)
        {

            (ContextMenuListView.Items[1] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(client.Folders[i].Name);//add Folder to Move To
            (ContextMenuListView.Items[2] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(client.Folders[i].Name);                
        }
```

how to I get subitem in Items[1] or Items[2] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ToolStripItemCollection.Add(string)` (DropDownItems.Add()) will return the new ToolStripItem ...

on the other hand, all other sub items are referenced by the `ToolStripItemCollection DropDownItems`

so the easy way to get the two created items is:

```
(ContextMenuListView.Items[1] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(client.Folders[i].Name);
(ContextMenuListView.Items[2] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(client.Folders[i].Name);
```

would become:

```
ToolStripItem firstItem = (ContextMenuListView.Items[1] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(client.Folders[i].Name);
ToolStripItem secondItem = (ContextMenuListView.Items[2] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(client.Folders[i].Name);
```

or to access all sub items:

```
foreach(ToolStripItem i in (ContextMenuListView.Items[1] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.OfType<ToolStripItem>())
{
   //...
}
```

or to access a specific sub item:

```
var specificItem = (ContextMenuListView.Items[1] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Item[0];
```